# Changing attribute source in JQuery calls a URL before actually using it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a web page with an iframe that initially has an empty src attribute with id checkout-window:

```
<div id="checkout-window" style="display:none"><iframe src=""></iframe></div>
```

I want to show the iframe inside in a JQuery UI modal, so once the user clicks on the checkout button it calls the placeOrder function, which uses JQuery to set the iframe source and then opens the modal:

```
placeOrder() 
{
  $("#checkout-window iframe").attr('src','placeorder.php');
  $("#checkout-window").dialog(
  {
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: true,
    position: 'center',
    show: "slide",
    hide: "slide",
    width: 720,
    height: 700,
    title: "Checkout Process"
  });
}
```

The problem is that script placeorder.php gets called twice and I end up with two orders in my DB! Also when the user closes the modal it calls placeorder.php again. When I comment out the dialog code (only the setting of the attribute remains) it indeed calls it once.

Why does setting the iframe src attribute already call the URL? How should I cope with this behaviour?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
placeOrder() 
{

  $("#checkout-window").dialog(
  {
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: true,
    position: 'center',
    show: "slide",
    hide: "slide",
    width: 720,
    height: 700,
    title: "Checkout Process",
    create: function(){
        $(this).append($("<iframe></iframe>").attr('src','placeorder.php'))
    }

  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried what you said but still there are multiple requests. I also tried to put in the src only on dialog open and to remove the src on dialog close. Didn't help either. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: try to load the placeorder.php by ajax

Comment: Yes that's sort of what I ended up doing. I an now issuing an ajax call to save the data through placeorder.php in the DB. After that I show the payment details form in a separate script in the iframe (I don't care how many times that one is referenced). Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Setting the src of an iframe will immediately start loading that content.

You will need to find another method of accomplishing this.

Comment: You *cannot* prevent an iFrame from loading its content, basically.